# Asp.net route two parameters to method in controller

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-ajax

I have the follwing function

```
[Route("/ClientReservations/{id}/{name}")]
        public ActionResult GetView(int id,string name)
        {
            ReservationHouseDetails houseDetails=null;
            repository.GetHousesForReservation(id).Where(item => item.Name.Equals(name)).ForEach(item => houseDetails = new ReservationHouseDetails()
            {
                House=item,
                Meal = repository.GetHouseMealForReservation(item.Id),
                Participants = repository.GetParticipantsHouseForReservation(item.Id)
            });

            return PartialView("ReservationHouseDetails", houseDetails);
        }
```

This method is called in this way

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
    {
        Url = Url.Action("GetView", "ClientReservations", new { id = Model.Reservation.Id, name = Model.SelectedHouseDetailsText }),
        HttpMethod = "get",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "divForSelectHouse"
    }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" class="SelectHouse"
                       value="Wybierz domek" />
            </div>
        </div>

    }
```

I have check in debbug mode and to value name is assigned value from model. However when it pass to presented method second parameter "name" is null. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in `Url.Action("GetView", "ClientReservations", new { id = Model.Reservation.Id, name = Model.SelectedHouseDetailsText })`

Your Url.Action generates `/ClientReservations/{id}?name={name}`

You must add a route before `"Default"` in `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetView",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ClientReservations", action = "GetView", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Or in `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetViewApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ClientReservations", action = "GetView", id = RouteParameter.Optional, name = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```